# Обновление JDK

Tags: java

Версия jdk меняется с завидной постоянностью. JRE можно обновить автоматически из панели java, а что делать с jdk? После смены 1.7.0.6 на 1.7.0.7 надо удалять старую и устанавливать новую? ОС windows 7 x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да плюнь на обновление JDK, обновление JDK это некритично, ну разве что когда будешь готовить продакшн версию обновись и собери под него свой прожект, а так не парься.

К тому же реальные пацаны из Google/Android продолжают использовать JDK 6, я согласен с ними и пока считаю что переходить на 7-ку еще рановато. Вот выйдет 8-ка, тогда перейдем под 7-ку. Общее правило: девелопмент надо весьти под стабильной версией.

Comment: а как же тот факт, что надо использовать все передовое, новое, чтобы не отстать?

Comment: в 7 ничего передового и революционного и нет, к сожалению.

Comment: Не стоит плеваться. В Java компиляторе, который является частью JDK так же находят и исправляют баги. Тоже самое и в прочих утилитах JDK.

Answer (score 1):

У меня все версии ныне актуальных JDK (6, 7) аккуратненько лежат в известной мне папочке, и я пользуюсь той, которая необходима в данный момент.

Answer (score 0):

Нет просто качаешь с оф сайта и устанавливаешь по умолчанию(т.е. все время нажимаешь далее в винде  так)

1.7.0.6 и 1.7.0.7 установится в разные папки.

Answer (score 0):

Удалять необязательно, но и захламлять диск множеством давно неиспользуемых версий JDK не стоит. Вообще JDK - это просто набор файлов и директорий, тоесть в конечном итоге установка JDK - это банальное их копирование.